# Busca por CSS selector usando o texto da label

Tags: html5, selenium-webdriver, css-seletores

Olá,

Estou querendo automatizar um formulário que possui 4 campos em que a única diferença é a label. Já procurei muito, mas não encontrei uma resposta que me ajudasse.
Estou automatizando com Selenium e Python.
O trecho HTML que eu preciso fazer a busca tem essa estrutura:

```html
<div class="formGroup"><label>Estado Expedidor RG<span class="danger"> * </span></label>
  <select required="" class="ant-select ant-select-enabled ant-select-selection ant-select-selection--single  dispatch_state"></select>
</div>
```

Eu gostaria de buscar por Estado Expedidor RG. A busca que eu fiz foi a seguinte:

```
combobox_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.formGroup .dispatch_state')
```

porém eu não consigo buscar os outros campos que estão no mesmo formulário, pois eles possuem os mesmos atributos e classes informados acima, diferenciando apenas na label. Como posso adicionar na busca que eu informei anteriormente, a label que eu quero usar como referência. Eu sei que um id ou até mesmo um atributo name já ajudaria, mas não tem.

Agradeço muito pela a ajuda e desculpa se eu deixei de informar alguma informação importante.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui contornar (não é da maneira que eu gostaria) inspencionando o campo que eu queria manipular, cliquei com o botão direito > Copy > Copy selector.
e copiei o caminho no parâmetro da busca que eu informei na dúvida.

Então ficou assim:

```
    combobox_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '#form-driver > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > select'
    )
```